# Change the binlog format MIXED to ROW

Tags: mysql, replication, amazon-rds, binlog, mysqlbinlog

I have a database that is running on AWS RDS (MySQl 5.7.22).

Currently, I have one master and 2 replicas running. My binlog format is **MIXED**. I have plans to change it to **ROW** based.

I want to change it during runtime (live environment) since it's our main database.

### Questions

1. What things do I have to consider before I change it?
2. What is the safest way to do it?
3. I am just wondering if there will be growth of the binlog size when I change it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use at the runtime.

```
SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'ROW';
```

or for the session

```
SET SESSION binlog_format = 'ROW';
```

see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log-setting.html) for more information.

Comment: how much the binlog size will be growth ?

Comment: You can set max_binlog_size and max_binlog_files. to get a grip on the maximumsite if the bin log.  the max size is max_binlog_size * max_binlog_files.

Comment: You should set it in the config, else it will be lost after the next restart.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  Nothing to worry about.

Long answer...

The size of the binlog is mostly irrelevant.  (It used to be defaulted to 1G, has recently defaulted to 100M.)

The binlog grows until it exceeds the configured limit.  Then a new binlog is started.  It is up to either `expire_logs_days` to purge old files or some other admin task.

The binlog may grow faster, or maybe slower; it really depends on the types of queries that are replicated.  For example, a million-row `UPDATE` (a naughty thing to do) will be one statement (the `UPDATE`) in `STATEMENT` mode and will be a million row-changes in `ROW` mode.  In this example, `ROW` will fill up more disk; the admin task will eventually clear it.